# Easiest Framework to build a quick POC Daap

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, rpc

So I'm trying to build the most simple Daap to make a POC. I just want to register messages/strings on a block so that any given duplicate messages are ignored.

I've done a lot of research but I'm overwhelmed by the information there's available. The problem I'm having is to have a decent test net/private net to test my application.

I've tried Hyperledger Fabric but there are some broken issues and it requires a lot of stuff that I don't yet fully understand (like docker and vagrant for instance)

I made a lot of progress working with Go-Ethereum framework which I can use the Web3j API to send my requests. But for some reason, I'm having difficulty now connecting to a ROPSTEN network or even creating a private network to test(using $geth --testnet or $geth --rpc and every possible combination). It just won't start or it will take too long and then it connects to Ethereum Blockchain which is not what I want(for now).

So does anyone know some framework or even a simple way to create our private network without geth?

I just need to initialize a private-net that I can use with web3j, then everything will fall into place.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely want to use `truffle` and `test-rpc`. It takes about two seconds to setup, and even less time to build a 'wireframe' dApp that will work without geth. Many, many people use this for full fledged development, let alone POC work.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle

Comment: sorry, I accidentally commented on the answer below when I wanted to answer here. It doesn't let me edit or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Create a folder on you c drive. In my case its amrik, you can rename to anything that you want.

// setup the server locally

> geth --datadir C:\amrik\datadir --dev console

// start mining server and keep the window open.

> geth --datadir C:\ amrik \datadir --dev --mine --minerthreads 1

// open new window start for the transactions

> geth --datadir C:\ amrik \datadir --dev attach \.\pipe\geth.ipc

Now are you ready to fire more commands.  this is private, so should not have any access issues. Let me know

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply. 
So I was able to use testrpc and it really worked liked a charm. But when testrpc is initiated, it creates 9 wallets by default. My question now is....how can I access the physically this wallet files? Or how can I reference them? access them?
For instance, when I use Mist or Ethereum Wallet and when I create a new account, it saves the account address in the keystore directory, and then I'm able to provide a location to retrieve the account (and respective password to unlock it).

Comment: I just need someway to access/use them. My app is in JAVA, I'm using web3j API. The testrpc log console outputs  "web3_clientVersion" everytime I try to run the app so I know that is working but if I wanted to simulate a transfer of funds between accounts, how can I achieve this using testrpc?

In the very end after the server has started and after "Mnemonic", there's a "Base HD Path: m/44' /60' /0' /0 {account_index}" but I don't really know if this what I'm looking for or even if it is a path that I can access to.